# asp.net unable to locate a resource file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Im attempting to utilize some custom script and css files within an asp page.  In Visual Studio 2010 I am not getting any warnings or errors as to the status of these files, but when I attempt to run the page, and I open the javascript console I get the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Here's how I am attempting to load the files in my ascx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
<link href="styles/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Anyone know whats going on here, why the browser can't locate the files but visual studio can?

Comment: Those would be relative links to the page your loading your user control into, try to use absolute links (/<root>/).

Comment: Whats rather interesting is I use the same relative linkage for two of the icons on the page, and they both work `<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Save_Button" ImageUrl="images/save1.gif" OnClientClick="save()" Onclick="SaveDefaults" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when the location of the .aspx file is different to the location of the user control (ascx).

When the user control is rendered in the browser it will actually have the location of the .aspx and tries to make the reference from that point. Whereas in VS, it will try to make the reference to the file from the .ascx location.

Therefore, try referencing the files as if you were making the references from the .aspx file location. It shouldn't give you any error when rendering that page.

Comment: Good catch, I needed to move the subfolders out to where the Default.aspx file was located, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've upvoted aleafonso's answer since he's correct. Now, to solve this issue, you can use the [ResolveClientUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx) method.

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("scripts/jquery.js"%>'></script>
```

Comment: +1. Thank you for adding value to the answer. This solution was unknown to me.